# Adding a Background Color to a Subview with an Alpha Setting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, subview, uicolor

I have a subview that shows once a button is pushed and it shows up fine. I have the subview showing a label along with it. I am just lost on how to change the background color of it and give it some transparency by adjusting it's alpha and setting the label's text color to something else. I know this is just like three to four lines of simple code but I'm at a lost now.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender 
{
    UIView *mySubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];

    [self.view addSubview:mySubview];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 50)];
    label.text = @"This is a label";

    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

It all runs fine, I'm just missing some pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code:

```
mySubview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.6 blue:.7 alpha.8]; // for example
label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Hope this help you.